# Python Runtime Customization on Google App Engine

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I am trying to use a pretrained tensorflow model to run predictions on Google App Engine. The model has a lambda layer and was trained on Python 3.5.2.

The standard runtime on Google App Engine is 3.7.2 and since the model has a lambda layer I will have to store the architecture in code and load the model weights in the newer Python version as per this issue on Github:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9595

I did not save the architecture/tuned parameters earlier so I cannot replicate the model in a newer Python version.

So I am trying to customize the python runtime on Google App Engine to 3.5 as per the documentation to insert my own Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python

# Create a virtualenv for dependencies. This isolates these packages from
# system-level packages.
# Use -p python3 or -p python3.7 to select python version. Default is version 2.
RUN virtualenv /env -p python3.5

# Setting these environment variables are the same as running
# source /env/bin/activate.
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

# Copy the application's requirements.txt and run pip to install all
# dependencies into the virtualenv.
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

# Add the application source code.
ADD . /app

# Run a WSGI server to serve the application. gunicorn must be declared as
# a dependency in requirements.txt.
CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

When I deploy the app and hit the respective url I get the same error about the Python runtime like it is still running on Python3.7. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Below is the latest error message:

```
File "predict_y.py", line 40, in <lambda>: NameError: name 'tf' is not defined
at call (/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/core.py:846)
at __call__ (/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:773)
at add (/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/sequential.py:185)
at _method_wrapper (/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py:457)
at from_config (/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/sequential.py:378)
at deserialize_keras_object (/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py:303)
at deserialize (/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/serialization.py:106)
at model_from_config (/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/model_config.py:55)
at load_model_from_hdf5 (/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py:168)
at load_model (/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py:146)
at predict_markets (/home/vmagent/app/main.py:230)
at dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py:1936)
at full_dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py:1950)
at reraise (/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:39)
at handle_user_exception (/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py:1821)
at full_dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py:1952)
at wsgi_app (/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py:2447)
```

Comment: can you please provide the error message or a screenshot?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the latest error message.

Comment: From the `name 'tf' is not defined` it seems that tensorflow is not installed. Can you post your `requirements.txt` file?